# C# COM Plugin System

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2013, com

I'm currently at a point where I really need some advice. In our company we mix many languages that are unmanaged like PowerBuilder or pure C++. For now we need a lot of code out of .NET. So my first purpose was why not just make a plugin system via COM.

This is what I'm trying to achieve at the moment. Everything works fine, the plugin system can load plugins. But as soon as I expose my plugin system to COM and try to load a plugin via, as an example VBS, I always get the the following error:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

From my research I found that this problem occurs when, during `Assembly.GetTypes()`, the type couldn't be loaded. Which is really strange as I have put my interface into it's own assembly and reference it by my plugin system and the plugin, so that the interface is always the same.

But as I debugged a bit more I found that actually the problem seems to not be my interface. The load problem actually happens when he tries to load the type of my class of the plugin which inherits of the interface. Maybe it's the interface or something else.

But to point out for now, as long as I use the plugin system via managed code directly there is no problem. As soon as I do it via COM I receive this error. So I assume that I'm missing or messing something up with COM.

At the moment I really need a solution but not just the solution an explanation of the solution would also be really nice because I actually want to understand what I messed up.

Here is the download link to the solution. Maybe you find someting.

[Solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7c4irynb05125c/PluginSystem.7z?dl=0)

```
        [ComVisible(true)]
    public bool Initialize(string dllPlugin)
    {
        try
        {
            string dllPluginPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Replace("IncoPluginSystem.dll", "") + "plugins\\";
            string completePluginPath = dllPluginPath + dllPlugin + ".dll";

            if (!File.Exists(completePluginPath))
            {
                pluginError = "The plugin could not be found in the plugins directory.";
                return false;
            }

            plugin = Assembly.LoadFile(completePluginPath);

            if (plugin == null)
            {
                pluginError = "No plugin loaded. Pls initialize first";
                return false;
            }

            foreach (Type t in plugin.GetTypes())
            {
                if (t.GetInterface("IPlugin") != null)
                {
                    pluginInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IPlugin;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            pluginError = e.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The Problem happens in the foreach loop where u access the Types of the assembly.

I added a more detailed Exception handling. This is the Error when i expose it to COM

> Could not load file or assembly 'IncoPluginSystemInterface, Version-1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PuplicKeyToken=497bca4abf979e3e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot finde the file specified.
>   Fusion Log:
>   WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.

The references of the DLL are just the standard ones of creating a .net library. Nothing added.

The structure of the plugin system is the following

```
IncoPluginSystem.dll
IncoPluginSystemInterface.dll
plugins
->IncoPluginSystemInterface.dll
->TestPlugin.dll
```

So the missing dll is actually at the 2 spots where needed. Maybe it's because the IncoPluginSystem.dll is loaded as a COM object so maybe the path is incorrect but I'm not sure. I tested and changed all I can imagine. So it definitly has to be something I messed up with COM.

I was able to locate the problem. It's actually really that my DLL is in the wrong place. As soon as i put the DLL into the GAC it works. So for now my question is - how can i determine where to put the dll where it was missing. In my exception i only see what dll is missing but not the path. Does anyone know how to determine this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It will be impossible for anyone to help you without seeing code. People shouldn't need to go off-site and download a zip to attempt to diagnose your issue. You need to determine where the error is occurring, and post the *relevant* code. Please see the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited thx for the advise, i was thinking of just posting the whole solution because the plugin system on it's own works well. It just stops working when exposed to COM. So i thought the best way to show u guys the problem is u guys let test it urself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to answer it myself. To Explain what was wrong. What I did to may help\improve others work in future.

I turned on the FusionLog in the Registry and on the LoaderException I checked for the FusionLog

```
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Exception exSub in ex.LoaderExceptions)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(exSub.Message);
                FileNotFoundException exFileNotFound = exSub as FileNotFoundException;
                if (exFileNotFound != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exFileNotFound.FusionLog))
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine("Fusion Log:");
                        sb.AppendLine(exFileNotFound.FusionLog);
                    }
                }
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
            pluginError = sb.ToString();
        }
```

After enabling the FisonLog on the Registry (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog (DWORD 1) I was able to see that the missing DLL is actually needed at the location of the executing program that call's the OLEObject to create an instance of the system via COM.

I wasn't aware of this, but yeah in some way it's rather logic. Luckily i didn't messed up anything on the code it was just in the wrong place.